# How to get contents of a text box using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textbox, getattribute

Below is the html code for the text box from which i have to fetch the value

```
<input id="textfield-3586-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-text-default" data-ref="inputEl" role="textbox" size="1" name="name" autocomplete="off" componentid="textfield-3586" type="text"/>
```

I have used

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@data-ref='formWrap']/div[4]/div/div/div/input")
element.getAttribute("value")
```

This does not return any value

Comment: can you use element.getText(); make sure you type something in the textbox before using this

Comment: use get_attribute('value')

Comment: I don't see value attribute in your html

Comment: get_attribute("value")  works.The page wasn't loaded and hence wasn't returning any value

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your xpath correct ?

I would recommend get Firefox and install the following extensions:

"Firebug","Firefinder for firebug", "Firepath". 
Copy ".//*[@data-ref='formWrap']/div[4]/div/div/div/input" in FirePath and click Eval. If screen stays blank then there is something wrong with your xpath or if it  highlights multiple fields then you know your xpath isn't specific enough.

2. See if you can send something to the textbox for example WebElement.sendKeys("send some text");
3. See if you can use the getText method for example: WebElement.getText();
   if this doesn't work try slow things down, use an implicit wait before you do the getText().
4. In firebug you can also look at the DOM properties. Make sure you are using the correct attribute